# How to prove the minimal resolution of double rational points can be achieved by iterated blow-ups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, blowup

In the Slodowy's survey on Kleinian singularities, there is a statement that the minimal resolution of Kleinian singularities can be obtained by iterated blow-ups, I want to know the detail of the proof of this claim.

And I also wonder that the how to blow up the variety we obtain after the first blow-up, since it is a subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^{n}\times\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$,  should we treat it as a subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^{2n}$?

This is the link of the survey mentioned above :

http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/sandra.rozensztajn/enseignement/Slodowy.pdf

Comment: I don't know much about Kleinian singularities, but the the fact that rational singularities can be resolved by monoidal transformations without normalizing is in [Lipman's paper](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~lipman/papers-older/%5B1969%5D%20Rational%20singularities%20with%20applications%20to%20algebraic%20surfaces%20and%20unique%20factorization.pdf) somewhere.

Comment: These are fairly deep results and can not be explained here. I would suggest that you start with Artin's paper and Mumford's paper (referred to in the above article) which deal with the surface case, which in some sense is the most important case and go from there.

Comment: @AolongLi My apologies: Lipman only deals with surfaces. I don't know much in higher dimensions.

Comment: @Hoot It is fair enough, since Kleinian singularities are singularities on surfaces.

Comment: @AolongLi : are you still interested in the question ?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Yes, I do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's answer the second question : it doesn't make sense to embedd $\Bbb P^{n-1}$ in $\Bbb A^n$ (any morphism from a projective variety to an affine variety is constant). Over complex numbers, we can take a local chart and compute the blow-up in the local chart, it means that we can always suppose that the blow-up is in the affine space.

There is an elementary proof if your definition of Kleinian singularities is  quotient $X = \Bbb C^2/ \Gamma$ where $\Gamma \subset \rm{SL}_2(\Bbb C)$ is a finite subgroup. Then, you just need to compute the equations of $X$ and compute explicitely the blow-up. Computing the blow-up is not hard, and computing the equations might be tedious especially for type $E$, but it's very easy for type $A$ and not too hard in type $D$.

If you use alternating definitions, the paper "Fifteen characterization of rational double points" by Durfee explains many characterizations of the Kleinian singularities, and prove their equivalence, in particular they are the only surfaces with a double point which can be resolved only using blow-up. But I am not sure he proves everything.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @AolongLi : you're welcome ! In fact I did almost all the computations in my master thesis, it will be online soon if you are interested (I still need to do a few corrections). Equations $\Bbb C^2/ \Gamma$ are tricky when $\Gamma$ is in type $E$, the notes about the McKay correspondance by Dolgachev are great.

Comment: I know Dolgachev's notes but I haven't started reading it. I am absolutely interested in your thesis! Please let me know when you put it online!

Comment: Ok sure I'll write an message here :) It should be in a few months, I'm doing several corrections now that I have a bit of time.

Comment: Thanks again! :)

Comment: @AolongLi : again, you're very welcome ! Also, there are very good ressources here as well : http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/McKay/

Comment: This webpage looks awesome! Added it to my favorites:)

Comment: Hi if you finish your thesis, could you send me a copy? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Aolong Li : Hi, you can send me an email (my university is UNIGE) and I'll be happy to send it to you the current version.